# how to calculate the duration of an uploaded mp3 file in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, audio, mp3

I have uploaded an mp3 file usinf JSP. Is there any way to find the duration of the uploaded mp3 file in seconds?

Given below is the part of the code:

```
        pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
        pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
        pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
        pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
        int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
        int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
        int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
            System.out.println("Content Type:"+contentType);
            System.out.println("PATAH:"+saveFile);
            System.out.println("Start :"+startPos);
            System.out.println("endPos :"+endPos);

        System.out.println("contentLength"+formDataLength);//Size of the file in Bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to know the audio length only by the file size, the best way is to using a library to do it.

Using MP3 SPI: http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/documents.html

example code, that return how many seconds the audio file has:

```
private static int getDurationWithMp3Spi(File file) {
    AudioFileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
    Map<?, ?> properties = ((TAudioFileFormat) fileFormat).properties();
    String key = "duration";
    Long microseconds = (Long) properties.get(key);
    int mili = (int) (microseconds / 1000);
    return (mili / 1000) % 60;
}
```

Comment: It is giving an exception like this "javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: file is not a supported file type"

Comment: May be you have to install the JMF:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html

Comment: Yes, it is the way. You have to check if you application is loading/using the JMF.

Comment: Installed JMF, still not working. This is what i have done.
File n=new File(path of the file);
then i have passed this file 'n' to the function.
I am using net beans to run JSP.

Comment: May be, I do not know how, you have to include the JMF jars and files.

Comment: Search for a JMF plugin : http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/9525/netbeans-media-player-module